# Avoid waiting on sending HTTP request via Oracle database

Tags: oracle, web-services, triggers

I have an application that is connected to an Oracle database where it can execute select, insert and update statements. I want to call a function in that application that would tell the Oracle database to send a http request.

My objectives:

- Fire and forget - the application and database don't care about the response or whether the request was successful
- The application and database should never wait for the response

I was thinking about these approaches:

1. Application inserts a row to a table, trigger after insert calls a db function that uses UTL_HTTP to perform the request
2. Application calls a db function that uses UTL_HTTP to perform the request via a select statement

What are the advantages/pitfalls of said approaches with regard to my objectives?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some thoughts of the top of my head, I'm sure there are other considerations:

1. If you do it in a trigger, the http request will go out even if you then decide to rollback the insert. So are you okay with having the http request sent but no row ends up in the table? If so, a trigger would be fine.
2. If you do it in a trigger, then any other interfaces or humans manually needing to load rows to the table will cause the http request to fire. Is that what you want? Then a trigger is great. If not, a trigger isn't so great.
3. Triggers are dropped if the table is dropped. If you do maintenance of the kind we do all the time in data warehousing (CTAS a new table, drop the old, rename the new to the old, etc..) you can easily lose your code because the code is contained in the trigger and the trigger disappears with the table drop. Triggers are not safe places for complex code. If you do end up using a trigger, consider having the trigger simply call a procedure, and store all your real code in that procedure.
4. If you decide to not use a trigger at all, you are better off writing a procedure than a function you call through a select statement. The point of a function is to return something, and in this case, you don't have anything from the http process you are wishing to return. And the select statement would be arbitrary. Just use a normal procedure call.

Comment: What happens when I use a trigger and the connection via UTL_HTTP.begin_request () fails on a timeout. Will other db operations wait until this is completed?

Comment: All calls in Oracle are synchronous, so yes, a call to some external thing that stalls will stall your originating session (the one doing the insert). If you want to make it asynchronous, you'd instead use the trigger to write rows to a special table, then have a dbms_scheduler job wake up every 10 seconds or so and find rows in that table to process, and send the http requests. Or you can have a scheduler job run 24/7 and loop , sleeping every 1 second (using dbms_lock.sleep) and watching for rows to process.

Comment: Scheduler jobs can also be event/message driven. No need for loops, unnecessary checks, or "special tables". Have the trigger (or any application process or procedure) post a message to the appropriate queue and parse the message in the scheduler job.

Comment: How many scheduler jobs do you want to fire? Seems like a lot of overhead at high voumes, not to mention dba_scheduler_job_run_details records.